# How to plot $x(t)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty }^\infty e^{-|t-2n|}$

Tags: graphing-functions, periodic-functions

How to graphically plot

$$ x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty }^\infty  e^{-|t-2n|}$$

Please tell me how to plot the graph of the above function.
Also please suggest some online tool where I can ploot this. I am having difficulty in plotting this as it involves two variables n and t.(It would be of great help if you would plot the graph from online graph plotters and paste the link here).thank you

Comment: Well... first *compute* this as a periodic function with period $2$ such that, for every $t$ in $[0,2]$, $$x(t)=\frac{\cosh(t-1)}{\sinh(1)}$$ then plot the function.

Comment: "(algebraic-graph-theory)" ??

Comment: couldnt find any approprate tag related to graphs. Thought this might be the one. :(

Comment: Why is this function periodic?

Comment: This is not (an appropriate tag). *Reading* the info of the tags would be a plus...

Comment: "Why is this function periodic?" Tell me.

Comment: The function will be periodic with period 2 if  x(t+2)=x(t). I cant understand mathematically why that happens?

Comment: and in fact, that is so: consider that $n$ spans from $- \infty$ to $+ \infty$, thus changing $n$ with $n+1$ ...

Comment: @Did Sir. From concepts of signal processing, I can understand that the function $e^{-|t|}$ will be shifted by two units for every n ranging from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Can you show us mathematically why $ \sum_{n=-\infty }^\infty  e^{-|t+2-2n|}=\sum_{n=-\infty }^\infty  e^{-|t-2n|}$.

Comment: Quite generally, for every fixed $k$, $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_{n+k}$$